# Как в sql создать БД с таблицами продукты и тип

Tags: sql, postgresql

Только начал изучать SQL. Есть задание:

В системе заданы таблицы

product(id, name, type_id, expired_date, price)

type(id, name)

Задание.

1. Написать запрос получение всех продуктов с типом "СЫР"
2. Написать запрос получения всех продуктов, у кого в имени есть слово "мороженное"
3. Написать запрос, который выводит все продукты, срок годности которых заканчивается в следующем месяце.
4. Написать запрос, который выводит самый дорогой продукт.
5. Написать запрос, который выводит количество всех продуктов определенного типа.
6. Написать запрос получение всех продуктов с типом "СЫР" и "МОЛОКО"
7. Написать запрос, который выводит тип продуктов, которых осталось меньше 10 штук.
8. Вывести все продукты и их тип.

Проблема в том что я даже не понимаю как создать эти таблицы, какие типы соединений нужно использовать, как их объединить и т.д.?

Comment: *как создать эти таблицы* [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createtable.html). *какие типы соединений нужно использовать, как их объединить* "FOREIGN KEY", там же.

Comment: А как связать таблицы. Я так понимаю надо использовать many to one

Comment: Разобрался сам, кому интересно вот ссылка на gitHub: https://github.com/AlexandarVysotskiy/AVysotskiy/commit/fc55d201534cf3fa8f1b7cdfcdfcf6ba6a5e7083